Can I make a message filter apply to subjectX without it applying to Re: SubjectX
I have a message filter in Thunderbird to automatically progress auto-generated messages with a subject of "Subjectx .... other stuff" into a folder.
Every now and again, someone replies to one of these, and I'd like to know about that by having it NOT diverted, but left in the Inbox.
I have a Message filter that says (with FiltaQuilla)
"Subject Regex Match" matches  "/^Subjectx /"    (there are not "s of course)

But I find this still files a subject of "Re: Subjectx ..." away.  Looking at the filter log this seems to agree that the "Re: " is removed before the filter is applied.
Has anyone got any tips of how to not remove the "Re: " (or, at least not get replies lumped in with the intended messages)?
